# How to count the delimiters in a string?

Tags: c#

I have a question...kind of basic but I thought I can take some help from you guys

I am encrypting a file and the information I encrypt is

```
LoginTxtBox.Text + "/" + PwdTxtBox.Text + "/" + InstNameTextBox.Text + "/" + DBNameTxtBox.Text;
```

When I decrypt it ... I am doing:

```
StringBuilder sClearText = new StringBuilder();
encryptor.Decrypt(sPrivateKeyFile, sDataFile, sClearText);

//username/password
string s = sClearText.ToString();
string[] split = s.Split(new Char[] { '/' });
if (split.Length == 4)
{
    split0 = split[0];
    split1 = split[1];
    split2 = split[1];
    split3 = split[1];
```

Now the requirement I got is I need to count the delimiters in the decrypted format of string and if there are more than 2 delimiter then its not a new application. If there is only one delimiter then its a never used application. I don't know how to to count the delimiters from the decrypt string...Help me plzz

Comment: The code you've shown implicitly knows the number of delimiters, doesn't it? (`split.Length - 1`) ;)

Comment: Side note: using pretty much any printable character to separate user-entered strings is bad idea. Please consider proper serialization to avoid all sorts of injection issues (i.e. password "a/b" would be awesome for your system).

Comment: @Dan Yes!! Searching for more ways to do that
Regex.Matches( s,  "/" ).Count .This worked perfectly. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @user1410658: Please also read the answers to [this previous question about storing encrypted passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607075/storing-encrypted-passwords).  Basically, even if you're encrypting passwords, unless you're using a cryptographically strong one-way hash algorithm, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @DanielPryden probably, but it *does* depend on the use case. It would be wrong in web user authentication, but for e.g. a password keeper application (to name an obvious example)...

Comment: @DanielPryden I am new to this site.... Thank you for your Suggestions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this code

```
Regex.Matches( s,  "/" ).Count
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you  user1410658

Answer (score 2):

Some more ways:

```
int delimiters = input.Count(x => x == '/');
```

-or-

```
int delimiters = input.split('/').Length - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you split the string on the character delimeter and the resulting array should contain one more than the number of delimeters?

Comment: Yes!! i thought of trying that but then thought of knowning diff ways of doing this stuff 
Regex.Matches( s,  "/" ).Count) worked perfectly.Thank you for your time :)