# Update a password if user name and old password match

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

This is the first time I run any type of queries and/or connect to a database through vb. I have looked up my problem on line but have not found exactly what I am looking for.

I have a simple login page on my windows application that runs out of a compact .sdf database. I need to add a procedure that allows the user to change the password.

If the user name in textbox1 and the password in textbox2 match what I have stored in my database, then replace the password with the values of textbox3.

So far I have been able to figure out how to create a new account and verify the log in. I log in using the following:

```
SELECT        username, userpassword
FROM            UserInfo
WHERE        (username LIKE @username) AND (userpassword LIKE @userpassword)
```

Then the procedure on my button:

```
' Check if username or password is empty
If txtPassword.Text = "" Or txtUserName.Text = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    'Clear all fields
    txtPassword.Text = ""
    txtUserName.Text = ""

    'Focus on Username field
    txtUserName.Focus()

Else

    'If the password and username match, open the main form.
    If Not UserInfoTableAdapter1.Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text) = Nothing Then

        Dim frmWelcome As New frmWelcomePage

        frmWelcome.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    Else


        MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid user name or password", "Invalid Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        'Clear all fields
        txtPassword.Text = ""
        txtUserName.Text = ""

        'Focus on Username field
        txtUserName.Focus()

    End If

End If
```

How can I use something similar to change the password?

Comment: You do not want to use `LIKE` with a password. Use an exact match (`=`) instead.

Comment: @pickypg Thanks, already changed it on my file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @pickypg said you should definitely look for an exact match with passwords and usernames. Also you should consider a one way hash for user passwords. **[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607946/2835914)** does a good job of describing the potential danger of storing plain text passwords. **[This article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)** has related information and is also amusing.

That aside the sql you're looking for might be something like this:

```
create procedure updateUserPassword
 @userName varchar(max)
,@oldHashedPassword nvarchar(128)
,@newHashedPassword nvarchar(128)
as
begin
set nocount on;
  if exists ( select 1 from UserInfo where username = @userName and userpassword = @oldHashedPassword )
  begin
    update UserInfo set userPassword = @newHashedPassword where username = @userName;
  end
  else
  begin
   raiserror('No record found for user', 16, 1);
  end
end
```